# Building optimal RC flying wing

Tags: wing, flying-wing

I have an EMAX motor that operates at maximum efficiency generating 200g of thurst. This is the only fixed parameter I have.

How do I find the most efficient wing design for this flying wing, considering my motor should push 200g in order to operate on its most efficient range.

I know the bigger the aspect ratio, more efficient the wing will be and more flight time.

I would like to use a KFm airfoil (cause of its simplicity on building it).

How an RC hobbyst (I am a mechanical engineer too), with not much knowledge on drag, lift coefficients... can come up with an optimal design?

EDIT:

Sorry for being too broad. Let's specify better:

1) my electronics weight (motor, esc, battery, servos...) will be at 50g;

2) I want to use a foam board, typical on rc plane community which is thin and lightweight

3) I want to optimize for flight time, not flight distance.

I am really lost at this, even after searching a lot. I know the vector diagram of my plane (weight is down, lift is up perpendicular to the wing, drag parallel to the wing and I know there are many types of drag but I would assume only the most relevant drag which is the one generated by air deflection and thrust is also parallel to the wing pointing forward).

The only vector that I know how to quantify is thrust and weight. The other 2 I am very lost!

EDITED so it can received answers.

Comment: You are going to need to decide what it is you are optimizing, for a start. As it stands this is way too broad. What is your takeoff weight? Is efficiency the most important factor? What is the mission? In theory, an infinite-span wing would be a very efficient solution (if you manage to stabilize the flying wing without sweep), but I have a feeling you're not after that answer.

Comment: You question is really broad. It would be easier to answer specific question about specific part of your design. You may also include your current knowledge so that answer is more adapted to you current understanding.

Comment: @AEheresupportsMonica I edited my question, sorry for not being specific!

Comment: @ManuH I made the question more specific, hope this clarifies!

Comment: Sorry, another nitpick: a Kline-Fogleman airfoil will not lend itself well to a flying wing, I'm afraid. If it has to be a flying wing you will need some combination of a reflex airfoil and wing sweep to achieve longitudinal stability. I will assume you can actually fit your avionics inside a fuselage or pod, otherwise your airfoil will also need sufficient thickness to not only carry the bending loads caused by lift, but to also house the electronics. Otherwise you could drop the flying-wing requirement, they are not as great once you look past the nice aesthetics.

Comment: @AEheresupportsMonica yeap! I know flying wings are not great on efficiency mainly because of the reflex. However they are a lot easier to build, lighter and easier to carry arond when compared to normal planes with fuselage/tail. Because I know flying wings are already not optimal, I would like to calculate the best chance I can get with then!

Comment: Just buy a Zagi: https://zagi.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an optimal design to have fun.  General guidelines:  Your model should weigh around 500 - 700 grams.  Wing span around 1.5 meters.  Chord around 0.2 meters.  But you really need to nail down your speed envelope.  Too fast will be difficult to control, too slow and it's an indoor delight but an outdoor nightmare (due to wind).

A good place to start would be a chunky reliable design similar to a Piper Cub or Cessna 152.  Shorter more highly loaded wings should help you find the sweet spot of around 7 to 25 mph, which is good for R/C planes.

Build an engine/battery/servo frame that can easily change out wings and empennage as you fine tune your design with gliding and powered flights.

You may wish to start with a slightly cambered KFm 1.  Slower speed and lower wing loading should give more endurance, but will be blown around by the wind and will actually be less efficient distance wise into the wind.  Go conservative on your first build.

Control surface dimensions can be had from foamies at your local hobby shop or R/C club, and more information is available at the RC Groups website.[image]

Comment: thank you so much! Very good advices :) But I still would like to get the math working with this new plane I wlil build. I already built hundreds of foam planes and I see that pretty small changes on the design have strong effects on performance (flight time). So this time I would like to stop spending time building planes till find a good performance and start researching/calculating it before building!

Comment: @Samul  you may consider moving from foam to balsa, which is more rigid and lighter.  Also, the KF will not be as efficient in slow flight, the one pictured was superseded by thin undercambered wings.  Building from scratch, only the wing ribs take much time, sheet balsa can be easily folded right over them.  The conventional tail is good to have for control at lower speeds, but a design like the E-flite Opterra may interest you.